# Angular 5 Browser back button not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6

I am working in angular 5 , and when click on a link then the view will show. And again click on another link , it show the view. Then i click on browser back button, the url will changed , but not change the view. Actually I want to view the previous view.

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
          //contain differnt path
        ]);
```

Comment: Im currently in the same situation, with a quick bit of googling I found this link.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3533-using-router-events-to-detect-back-and-forward-browser-navigation-in-angular-7-0-4.htm

It seems to cover the issue..

Comment: I'd need to see more of the code that configures your RouterModule. Make sure you use forRoot and forChild correctly: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forChild

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue now.